# Mac installer command hangs on 10.5/10.6 but not 10.4

Tags: macos

What would cause the Mac `installer` command to hang when installing an app from a shell script? The last output the installer gets to is "Preparing Target Volume". This behavior is observed on 10.5 and 10.6 but not 10.4.

Comment: can we have more info about the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Activity Monitor to take a Sample (stack trace) or a hung process and see where it's stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this hanging behavior on my installs.  Quitting the iphone simulator fixes mine.